# A variable becomes undefined when used within start_urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to figure out as to how I can append `pid` to the `base_url` in order to make them qualified urls. I know I can use this `https://www.somesite/search/?id=` directly within `start_urls` to achieve that but I wish to know how I can use this variable `base_url` within `start_urls` as it currently throws an error indicating that `base_url` is not defined. `ID`'s within the text file are like `2354`, `0957` e.t.c.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "contentgrabber"

    base_url = "https://www.somesite/search/?id="

    with open('numbers.txt','r') as f:
        item_pids = [id_num.strip() for id_num in f.readlines()]
        start_urls = [f"{base_url}{pid}" for pid in item_pids]

    def parse(self,response):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'
    })
    c.crawl(SomeSpider)
    c.start()
```

How can I use `base_url` as a variable within `start_urls` keeping the current implementation intact?

Comment: Code that's inside a `class`, but not inside any method of that class, is a somewhat unusual situation.  This code will executed *once*, when the class is defined (in other words, it will have absolutely nothing to do with your crawling process), and the scoping rules in effect are a bit weird.  That should probably all be inside a method, but I'm not familiar with scrapy to tell you how it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is [`def start_requests(self):`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.1/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests)

and the reason it is whining about `base_url` is because that is a class (or instance) variable, and thus needs to be qualified with either `self.base_url` or `SomeSpider.base_url`, depending on where the code is run